# How to get rid of asset catalog compiler warning "app icon is required for apps ... targeting iOS 7.0 ..."

Tags: ios8, icons, warnings, xcode6.1, xcasset

I have a APP targeting *only* iOS8.1 so i set the AppIcon in `Images.xcasset` like this ...

[image: Attributes inspector]

The icons configuration looks like this:

[image: AppIcon]

My app does **not** targeting iOS 7.x and below so i'm wondering how i could get rid of Asset Catalog Compiler Warning: "A 60x60@2x app icon is required for iPhone apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later". See sample code [iOS8.1 App](https://github.com/augustjohann/iOS8App).

Answer (score 3):

The error says "targeting iOS 7.0 and later", that means 8.0 as well. You are missing 2x icon sizes that are required for iOS 7 as well as for 8.

3x sizes are used only in iPhone 6+, every other iOS device uses 2x size (or even 1x for older iPads, but that doesn't seem to be relevant in your case as you are targeting iPhones only)

Comment: So I will choose option "iOS7 and Later Sizes" (even if it is not the target i want ...) and add the 2x size icons. But it's not clear why the 2x size icons placeholders will not be displayed when the option "iOS8 and Later Sizes" in the attributes inspector is selected!? Thank you ...

Comment: I am not sure why they aren't displayed, probably yet another bug in xcode